# Array sum returns NaN

Tags: javascript, html, foreach, sum, nan

I have an array with three values, and 1 seperate value all acquired from a form.

[image]

I am trying to multiply  the top number (3) with the others (12, 3 and 31) and add those up.

This is what i tried:

HTML:

```
 <p>Aantal sets: <span id="dynamicSet"></span></p>
        <table id="resultTable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col">Hoeveelheid</th>
                <th scope="col">Gewicht x KG</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td class="HoeveelheidField"><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
                <td class="GewichtField"><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td class="HoeveelheidField"><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
                <td class="GewichtField"><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td class="HoeveelheidField"><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
                <td class="GewichtField"><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

And my JS:

```
var HoeveelheidArr=[];
var total = 0;
const setAmount = document.getElementById("dynamicSet").innerHTML;

function getData(){
    $('#resultTable .HoeveelheidField > input ').each(function() {
        HoeveelheidArr.push($(this).val());
    });

    console.log(HoeveelheidArr);

       HoeveelheidArr.forEach(function getReps (value) {
           console.log(value);
           for(var i = 0; i < HoeveelheidArr.length; i++){
               total += value[i] * setAmount;
           }

       });
    console.log(total);
}
```

However as you may see in the picture i keep getting Not a Number back from the console. Despite the console showing all of them appear as ints? Do you see what I do wrong? I also tried:

```
parseInt(value[i])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `setAmount` variable is a string from `innerHTML`.

Use `parseInt()` on both variables:

```
total += parseInt(value[i]) * parseInt(setAmount);
```

**Update**

After a deeper review, you got a couple of other problems.

- Your `setAmount` variable is `""`, because it's not set in the HTML.
- You are looping through the `HoeveelheidArr` twice
- You should use `value` instead of `value[i]`

I made a working example:

```js
var HoeveelheidArr = [];
var total = 0;
const setAmount = document.getElementById("dynamicSet").innerHTML || 0;

function getData() {
  HoeveelheidArr = [];
  total = 0;
  $('#resultTable .HoeveelheidField > input').each(function() {
    HoeveelheidArr.push($(this).val() || 0);
  });

  console.log("HoeveelheidArr:", HoeveelheidArr);

  for (var i = 0; i < HoeveelheidArr.length; i++) {
    console.log("setAmount:", setAmount);
    total += parseInt(HoeveelheidArr[i]) * parseInt(setAmount);
  }

  console.log("Total:", total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Aantal sets: <span id="dynamicSet">1</span></p>
<table id="resultTable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col"></th>
    <th scope="col">Hoeveelheid</th>
    <th scope="col">Gewicht x KG</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="HoeveelheidField">
      <INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1">
    </td>
    <td class="GewichtField">
      <INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="HoeveelheidField">
      <INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1">
    </td>
    <td class="GewichtField">
      <INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="HoeveelheidField">
      <INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1">
    </td>
    <td class="GewichtField">
      <INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="getData()">Test</button>
```

Comment: No luck! I am still getting NaN :(

Comment: You are a hero! I knew i was in a rabbit hole with the double loops. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

why are you using value[i] value is not an array it's just a number.

```
console.log([value[i]);
```

the value[1] and value[2] is undefined that why you are getting NaN

If you tell me what do you want to do through this code, I can correct it